# Facebook how to get actual photo URL using Graph API?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

It is possible to get the actual image url of a Facebook image using the Graph api??

For instance, for the below photo 
http://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=357755307655174

the actual URL is
https://fbcdn-sphotos-a-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-ash4/252428_530045532341_5136_n.jpg

Is there some graph api way to achieving this?

Comment: Hi satheeshj did you able to make this thing work? Can we retrive any video source or photo source? ( Like do by facebook video downloaders, instagram video downloaders) Or are these downloaders just scraping the site. Eventhough scraped we cant get the real source of the URL

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> Is there some graph api way to achieving this?

Therefore, you’d have to look at the `source` field of the [photo](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/photo/) object:

> source:
>
> The source image of the photo - currently this can have a maximum width or height of 720px, increasing to 960px on 1st March 2012
>
> string representing a valid URL

That’ll give you the original size the photo was uploaded for smaller images, or resized to max. 960px in each direction.

For even larger sizes, you’d have to check the `images` field:

> images:
>
> The 4 different stored representations of the photo
>
> array of objects, containing height, width, and source fields

This “promises” to deliver much larger sizes (f.e. 2048×1417px) – but be aware, these entries will still deliver a smaller image if the original one wasn’t as large as requested.

Comment: So I will have to add `user_photos` permission? Darn! 
I did not mention this in my question, but the photo in question is uploaded BY ME from MY APP.. FB, after uploading, returns only Photo ID and POST ID... Even if I am the one uploading the photo, is `user_photos` permission the only way to get the source URL?

Comment: `source` field is Deprecated. Use `images` instead.

Answer (score 17):

- From https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api :

> By default, not all fields in a node or edge are returned when you
>   make a query. You can choose the fields or edges that you want
>   returned with the `fields` query parameter.

That's why when you retrieve a photo, you may only get `created_time`, `name` and `id`.

- From https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/photo/ :

`source` field is deprecated in latest API (v2.8). Use `images` instead.

So your query may look like this:

```
GET graph.facebook.com/{photo-id}?fields=images
```

Response should be like this:

```
{

"images":[
    {
        "height":358,
        "source":"https://scontent.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-9/15327427_585435148333529_xxxxxxxxxxxx_n.jpg?oh=xxxxxxxx&oe=xxxxxxxxx",
        "width":518
    },
    {
        "height":320,
        "source":"https://fb-s-c-a.akamaihd.net/h-ak-xtl1/v/t1.0-0/p320x320/15327427_xxxxxxxxxxxxxx_n.jpg?oh=xxxxxxxxxx&oe=xxxx&__gda__=xxxxxxxxxxxx",
        "width":463
    },
    {
        "height":130,
        "source":"https://fb-s-c-a.akamaihd.net/h-ak-xtl1/v/t1.0-0/p130x130/15327427_xxxxxxxxxxxxxx_n.jpg?oh=xxxxxxxxxxx&oe=xxx&__gda__=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
        "width":188
    },
    {
        "height":225,
        "source":"https://fb-s-c-a.akamaihd.net/h-ak-xtl1/v/t1.0-0/p75x225/15327427_xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx_n.jpg?oh=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx&oe=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx&__gda__=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
        "width":325
    }
],
"id":"585435148333529"

}
```

Comment: Deprecated in 8.0

Answer (score 3):

Request the field attachments, where you will find the original image.

```
&fields=picture.type(large),attachments
```

Answer (score 2):

There seems to be lack of documentation for this. It can simple be achieved in this way. In that url http://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=357755307655174 , take out the id of the pic represented by **fbid**.In the above case it is **357755307655174**. Now do a graph api query, to this object https://graph.facebook.com/357755307655174 . This will return a JSON with all the aspect ratio's present in their database and their actual URL's. Each data field following the format

```
{
      "height": 1080, 
      "source": "https://scontent-a.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-xpf1/t31.0-8/10296099_566697856780203_6555830953677139074_o.jpg", 
      "width": 1980
}
```

Use the Graph Explorer to check once again the format of returned JSON data.The source is what you are looking for.

Comment: I don't understand how you got this result. I have a picture id (743109952401466) and now I want to get url of this picture. So it would be something like this `https://graph.facebook.com/v2.5/743109952401466?access_token=my_token` But it gives me JSON output only with `created_time`, `nam`e and `id` of this picture, no url. How can I can JSON with `source` field?

Comment: @tyskaj - I ran into this too and learned elsewhere that you need to specify what additional fields come back with your request using the `?fields=link` query parameter.  So your URL in your comment should be:  `https://graph.facebook.com/v2.5/743109952401466?access_token=my_token&fields=link`.

Comment: With v2.8 and v2.9, we get only  created_time, name and id.

Answer (score 0):

```
    new GraphRequest(
            facebookToken,
            String.format("/%s/photos", idAlbum),
            parameters,
            HttpMethod.GET,
            response -> {
                try {
                    JSONArray photoArray = response.getJSONObject().getJSONArray("data");
                    photosAlbumAfterPagination = response.getJSONObject().getJSONObject("paging").getJSONObject("cursors").getString("after");
                    Gson gson = new Gson();
                    Type type = new TypeToken<List<FacebookPhotoResponse>>() {
                    }.getType();
                    List<FacebookPhotoResponse> list = gson.fromJson(photoArray.toString(), type);
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
    ).executeAsync();
```