# How to display actual images of facebook photos using only id (graph API)

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am using the facebook graph API to get photos.

```
        FB.api(
                "/me/photos",
                function (response) {
                    if (response && !response.error) {
                        console.log(response);
                    } else {
                        console.log(response.error);
                        alert(response.error);
                    }
                }
        );
```

The only information Im getting back for each photo in the `data` object is `created_time`, `id`, and `name` so Im not sure how to buid displayable images out of this data.

I have tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24250232/1652535) answer to try use the id to get the actual photo url but it is only giving back the same information there.

Does the permissions have an affect on the data that you receive back? As I am still in the submission process for this. I just assumed it would work anyway but give a permissions warning at the top of the pop up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to explicitly specify which fields you want to receive starting with v2.4. For example

```
/me/photos?fields=id,link,images
```

See

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog/#v2_4
- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/photo#Reading

> **Declarative Fields**
>   To try to improve performance on mobile networks, Nodes and Edges in v2.4 requires that you explicitly request the field(s) you need for your GET requests. For example, GET /v2.4/me/feed no longer includes likes and comments by default, but GET /v2.4/me/feed?fields=comments,likes will return the data. For more details see the docs on how to request specific fields.